# Scrambled Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C! So I get two equal length integer arrays as inputs and a len, which will always be equal to the len of the two arrays. I am supposed to verify if the integers in array A are equal to the integers in array B, order does not matter.

So for example, the following is ok:

```
A[:)] = {1,2,3}
B[:(] = {3,2,1}
```

But the following is not ok:

```
A[:)] = {1,1,1}
B[:(] = {1,2,3}
```

This is my code below with a sample test I put in main.c. However, my code fails to produce the right answer. But I am not sure why and I was wondering if someone could help point out where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//flag = 1 means the two arrays are equal, or empty
//flag = 0 means that the two arrays are not equal

int scrambled( int a[], int b[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    if (len == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        flag = 0;

        for( j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if( a[i] == b[j])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 0)
        {
            printf("Number not found\n");
            return flag;
        }

    }

    printf("Here is flag: %d\n", flag);
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    int array[100] = {1,1,1};
    int array2[100] = {1,2,3} ;

    int len = 3;

    scrambled(array,array2,len);
}
```

Comment: Show us what output you're getting.

Comment: If I run the code right now, the output I get is a 1, but it should be a 0 since the two arrays are not equal o.o

Comment: Have you thought *at all* about what your code does when given those arrays? Because it's extremely obvious that all of those `1`s will be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code only checks if every number in a[] exists in b[] and not the other way around.
a[] only contains 1's --> {1,1,1}. It checks all three 1's against b[] and every time it finds the 1 in b[].

The code should also check if every number in b[] exists in a[]. If you add that, then your code is complete.

This works.. (note that bubble sort is slow for large arrays!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void bubble_sort_ints(int a[], int len)
{
    int i, j, t;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

static int scrambled(int a[], int b[], int len)
{
    bubble_sort_ints(a, len);
    bubble_sort_ints(b, len);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
    int b[5] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3};

    printf("%s\n", scrambled(a, b, 5) ? "ok" : "not ok");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me too! :) What you can also do, instead of adding another loop, is count the sum of A and B while you're in the for(i..) loop. So:
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum_a += a[i];
    sum_b += b[i];
(...etc...) and then at the end check if sum_a and sum_b are equal. They should be.

Comment: This would report `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}` and `{1, 1, 2, 3, 3}` as equal when they are not (even with the sum check)

Comment: That is indeed true @MattMcNabb. It's safer to sort both arrays and then compare them.

Comment: "If you add that, then your code is complete." -- Obvious nonsense. "It's safer" -- It's not a matter of safety, but of simply getting the correct result. Adding the elements of the first array and then looking up the elements of the second is another method.

Answer (score 2):

```
int scrambled( int a[], int b[], int len){
    int i, j, flag;
    char flags[len];

    if (len == 0) return 1;
    memset(flags, 0, len);
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        flag = 0;
        for( j = 0; j < len; ++j){
            if( a[i] == b[j] && flags[j]==0){
                flags[j] = flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That `else return 0` is wrong -- {1,1} vs. {1,1} will return 0.

Comment: @JimBalter sure, i misunderstand. fixed.

Comment: Nice solution, very efficient.

Comment: @Gerber See my answer ... even simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the problem with your code is that you were not doing an equality test, but, really, an inclusion test.

Please note, however, that even repeating the comparison with the arrays interchanged yields wrong results if you bother about *repeated* elements.  E.g., try with `{1,1,2}` and `{2,2,1}`.

Here is a quick-and-dirty (yet mildly efficient) solution.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//flag = 1 means the two arrays are equal, or empty
//flag = 0 means that the two arrays are not equal

int scrambled(int a[], int b[], int len)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int flag;


    if (len == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;

        for(j = i; j < len; j++)  // start with j = i
        {
            if(a[i] == b[j])
            {
                // we got a match, hence forget about b[j]
                b[j] = b[i];

                // one match is enough for the current iteration
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }


        if(flag == 0)
        {
            printf("Number not found\n");
            return flag;
        }

    }

    printf("Here is flag: %d\n", flag);
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    int array[100] = {1,1,1};
    int array2[100] = {1,2,3} ;

    int len = 3;

    scrambled(array,array2,len);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you think that swap makes any sense. a = {1,2,1}, b={1,2,3} is an obvious case that incorrectly returns 1. What you really want to do is move the last element of b to the one matched (and shorten b).

Comment: Swap is necessary to preserve non-matching elements for future iterations.  And nope, a = {1,2,1}, b={1,2,3} does not return 1.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `j = i` ... but then you don't need to swap, just `b[j] = b[i]`, if you don't mind destroying `b`.

Comment: You have it backwards -- it needs to be `b[j] = b[i]`

Answer (score 0):

What you're code is actually doing is telling you if every value in first array can be found in second array.
I suggest you to run the function 2 times by swapping said arrays and compare the result :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//flag = 1 means the two arrays are equal, or empty
//flag = 0 means that the two arrays are not equal

int scrambled( int a[], int b[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    if (len == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;

        for( j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if( a[i] == b[j])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
            return flag;

    }
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    int array[100] = {1,1,1};
    int array2[100] = {1,2,3} ;

    int len = 3;

    if (scrambled(array,array2,len) && scrambled(array2,array,len))
        printf("Equal\n");
    else
        printf("Not equal\n");
}
```

Output is `Equal` for `{1,3,2} ; {1,2,3}` and `Not equal` for `{1,1,1} ; {1,2,3}`.

Comment: That's still wrong -- it just checks that each set contains the members of the other, it doesn't test them for equality, so {1,1,2} will match {1,2}, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. Your code detects if all the elements of array1 are in array 2 but not the other way around. Try calling

```
scrambled(array2,array,len);
```

and you'll see.

Comment: Um, the OP already knows their code doesn't work, and in effect did exactly what you suggested. Please post real answers.

Comment: (I agree I was pretty terse. That said, at the time I posted, the OP did not have any idea at all **why** their code was returning a false positive. Yes there's a leap from this insight to correct code, but shouldn't there be a balance between pointing the way and writing all the code to a solution?)

Answer (score 0):

Using ideas of BLUEPIXY and user3435489:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool match_scrambled( int a[], int b[], int len)
{
    if (len == 0) return true;

    int bx[len], nbx = len;
    memcpy(bx, b, sizeof bx);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        for (int j = 0;; ++j)
        {
            if (j == nbx)
                return false;

            if( a[i] == bx[j])
            {
                bx[j] = bx[--nbx];
                break;
            }
        }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,1,1};
    int array2[] = {1,2,3};

    if (!match_scrambled(array, array2, sizeof array / sizeof *array))
        printf("no ");
    printf("match\n");
    return 0;
}
```